# Integral curves between components of boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $V$ be a vector field on (for simplicity) $\Sigma=S^2\times[0,1]$. What conditions on $V$ are necessary and sufficient to ensure that the integral curve through any $x\in\partial\Sigma$ intersects each connected component of $\partial\Sigma$ exactly once?